# how to set automation for aws billing notification for financial department

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, automation, payment, billing

I'd want to automate aws billing.
In my situation, every month from 1 to 5th data I get an aws bill pdf and share it with the finance department for payment.
How can I automate this or use aws lambda to do this?
in short, I want to send a billing pdf in the root account to some limited mail address on a particular date.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for any sort of programming solution here. You just need to [add a billing contact email address](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-email-cc/) in your root account.

Comment: that's grate idea thanks